# How do you use 'create!' with strong_params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

Ok, so before installing [strong_params](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters), using `MyBook.create!` would work, but now it doesn't.

Here's my code

```
class AuthorsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @author = user.authors.build
  end

  def create
    @author = Author.new(author_params)
    if @author.save
      @book = MyBook.create!(:author_id => @author.id,
          :user_id => @author.user_id)
        )
   else
     render :new
  end
end
```

I tried

```
@book = MyBook.create!(params.require(:my_book).permit(
          :author_id => @author.id,
              :user_id => @author.user_id)
        )
```

but am getting `Required parameter missing: my_book`

What am I doing wrong? I can update each attribute one by one but that doesn't seem efficient. I understand that I can't mass-assign protected attributes, but without having to assign the attributes in my model (because of strong_params), I don't understand how I can get this to work.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your create does not work because you didn't `.save` your `@author` object first, so it has no `id`. Use `@author = Author.create(author_params)` instead of a new

Comment: @MrYoshiji sorry, I actually am saving the author & forgot to include it in there. I just edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So before, you weren't REALLY using params

```
@book = MyBook.create!(:author_id => @author.id,
      :user_id => @author.user_id)
    )
```

If you were using params in the "mass-assignment" way, it would have looking like:

```
@book = MyBook.create!(params[:book])
```

Since you are pulling out the id's yourself, it's easier to do:

```
@book = MyBook.create! do |mybook|
  mybook.author_id = @author.id
  mybook.user_id =  @author.user_id
end
```

Comment: Yes, I can't use `@book = MyBook.create!(params[:book])` because all the foreign keys return as nil. Your solution works but am just wondering if you had a better way of doing this or is this solution just fine? Thanks btw

Comment: You should probably accept nested attributes of Author inside of MyBook (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html ), that way `MyBook.create!(params[:book])` would handle everything.